# Can't see deployed contract in truffle console

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, console

As seen in the screenshot, I deploy a contract named `TulkerSale` using Ganache. Then in truffle console, `TulkerSale.deployed()` returns an error...

How can I access the deployed contract in the console?

[image]

Comment: How does your truffle.js look like? Please try ``truffle console --network development``.

Comment: I managed to access it by using `TulkerSale.at('here i copy the contract address which is displayed in the deploy output')`

Answer (score 1):

"TulkerSale" is the name of the contract but it does not represent an instance.

```
<contractName>.at("<address>")
```

That will get you the deployed contract account.

> at(): Create an instance of MyContract that represents your contract at a specific address.
>   deployed(): Create an instance of MyContract that represents the default address managed by MyContract.
>   new(): Deploy a new version of this contract to the network, getting an instance of MyContract that represents the newly deployed instance.

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract

Answer (score 0):

let tulkerSale = await TulkerSale.deployed()

https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/how-to/contracts/interact-with-your-contracts/